# Слитно или раздельно пишется словосочетание "не красивый"?

Tags: частица-не, слитно-раздельно

Слитно или раздельно пишется сочетание "не красивый поступок"?

Answer (score 2):

Все зависит от контекста.
Если частица **"не"** используется для отрицания того, что поступок ***красивый***, то такое словосочетание пишется раздельно:

> Это был не красивый поступок, как тебе могло показаться, а просто
> очередное проявление твоего бахвальства.

Если же мы просто хотим употребить слово **"некрасивый"**, то конечно же будем писать его без пробела:

> Это был некрасивый поступок, тебе должно быть стыдно.